# Extracting data from a file with Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Lets assume this is my file:

```
MSH|^~\&|Xatidok|V10.0.2.000|OSestra|x-tention|201203060855||ADT^A03|2914|P|2.3^AA&BB
EVN|A03|201203060855|201203060855|01|Fidani
PID|||00019380|2012049008^120005548^302830|PATIDOK-person^InRid^|Rudi|19111111|F|||Rose.  
NK1||IRergrun^RROSlf^||Rose ^^Wels^^4600^A|07242123123|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
PV1||I|1212^G442^G442-||0|||||||||||2012049008|General|||||||||||||||||||12|||||201202060927|||||||
```

While executing the script the user as a condition press lets say **NK1**

How can i disply the row which starts with **NK1** as it is in the file based on user's criteria.

`P.S i am doing it in Bash Script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use read to get the user's selection. Then search for the string selected using `grep`. The `^` fixes the search from the start of the line.

> ```
> echo -n "enter criteria:"
> read string
> grep '^'"${string}" file
> ```

Comment: Yes i can grep it but how i can match it with user's input in order to fetch that row ?

Comment: post updated - does that help?

Comment: Yes man, thanks a lot!

Comment: you don't need both single and double-quotes here, it's OK to have `^` inside double-quotes.  `grep "^$string" file` works just as well and is easier to read.